# What are the possible meanings for the word "range" in Math

Tags: meaning, mathematics

On the [mathematical website](https://brilliant.org/daily-problems/place-primes/) with some problems, there is a statement.
"The range of my tiles is a prime number".

tiles are just some squares with numbers or a set of numbers. For example, I can have 3 tiles with the numbers on them 3,5,7. What will be the range for these 3 tiles 3,5,7? is it 7-3=4 or something else?

Usually, I understand the range as "from 2 to 5" like the lower and upper border. Something like 2 or more numbers which describes the border of something, but not just one single number.

Comment: Yes, in that specific context, range is a number (max minus min). But this isn’t really about English - it’s more Maths lingo.

Comment: @Lawrence I would say that the range of those tiles would be inclusive of both the highest and lowest number. That is 7-2 =5 (a prime as it happens). If a tradesman starts a job on the 3rd of the month and finishes it on the 7th he's worked on it for 5 days and will invoice appropriately. The range of numbers on the tiles is analagous.

Comment: ELU expects basic research, where easily available, to accompany questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to *dictionary.cambridge.org*, one meaning of "range" is *the amount, number, or type of something between an upper and a lower limit*

If we understand the question to refer to the numbers printed on the tiles, the range of [3,5,7] is 7-3 = 4

I thought this was a trivial question but, having been voted down on it because someone does not understand the range of [3,5,7] to be 7-3 = 4, I add the following.

The use of "range" in mathematics is explained in simple terms in https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/range.html

This mathematical definition is consistent with and identical to the Cambridge Dictionary definition that I have quoted.

Comment: I have down voted the answer as it does not agree with the definition you have given. The range is not "4".

Comment: Do we have a semantic problem? This is simple arithmetic but clearly you do not see it like that. The amount or number between lower limit 3 and upper limit 7 is (7-3) = 4. This is the normal mathematical understanding of range, as in a "range of values". What justification do you have for thinking otherwise?

Comment: I've downvoted because the question is so obviously off-topic on ELU. The word 'range' in the Xmax -Xmin definition is basic stats, so the question is being asked on the wrong site as well as being ill-formed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I too thought it a rather basic question as regards meaning, but it seems easier to answer questions than to shunt them. Life is short. In the event, I was surprised that my simple and correct answer was downvoted, so perhaps the question is not so basic as you and I imagine.

Answer (score 0):

> What will be the range for these 3 tiles 3,5,7?

There is no "range" for the tiles themselves.

The range = the range of values that are printed on the tiles, and that is "the prime numbers from 3 to 7 inclusive."